# rmarkdown journal article templates

Tags: r, r-markdown

I recently started to use `r-markdown` to prepare journal articles with the handy templates from `rticles`. However, we ended up with submitting in Word rather than LaTex. Collaborators prefer Word, and at the moment, not all journals accept LaTex but all journals accept Word. Is there a place to get a collection of `r-markdown` templates to generate journal articles for Word document like `rticles` for LaTex?

Comment: Never heard of a repo like that. But you could get a normal word template and use it with Rmarkdown: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html

Comment: Thanks @JBGruber. Journals’ styles vary a lot. Pre-made Templates would save users time

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you already found the option of editing the YAML:
output:
word_document:
reference_docx: template.docx

However, from  experience, the best is to export the PDF as a word document (without figures) and add them later on.

I think what you are stating is really true and certainly helding Rmarkdown adoption.
Cheers